# Add row into existing table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

May I know how do I insert items into my table body? My code doesn't seems to work.

```js
var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody");

var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

var newCell = tableRef.insertCell(0);

var myTextTwo = "hello world";

var newText = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);

newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

```html
<table id="myList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product ID</td>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you check your JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: @Alvin you have omitted `[0]` from `.getElementsByTagName()` and you also try to add the new cell to the tbody, not the new row as you have to. Check out my answer for a more detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38248819/6313073

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array.  You need to append `[0]` to select the first element in the array.

You are also trying to use `insertCell` on `tableRef`, when you should be using it on `newRow`:

```js
var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

var myTextTwo = "hello world";

var newText = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);

newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

```html
<table id="myList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product ID</td>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What if I'd like to do a for-loop to loop through the first column element in the table? @Turnip

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different question. You should open a new one and mark this as answered if your initial problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to:

**1)** Put `[0]` after `.getElementsByTagName()` like below, **as this method returns an array of elements**, unlike `.getElementById()`, which returns the first instance:

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
```

**2)** Use the `.insertCell()` in the row you want the cell to be, in our case `newRow`, not on the table's `tbody`:

```
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
```

**Your correct JavaScript code should be**:

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
var myTextTwo = "hello world";
var newText = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);
newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

**You can also check out the following snippet**:

```js
var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
var myTextTwo = "hello world";
var newText = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);
newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

```css
#myList {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#empty {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id = "myList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product ID</td>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>

     <!--- This row is for adding a border-bottom line -->
    <tr>
      <td id = "empty" colspan  ="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```